Pushing master branch after merging detached head creates 2 commits instead of 1
I did the following:

Checkout detached head with specific id.
Make changes to detached head and save it in a new branch gallery-section-detached-head.
Merge gallery-section-detached-head into local master branch.
Push local master branch to remote master branch. When doing this an editor pops up with the message "Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary" and I'm forced to add a commit message.
Instead of adding just 1 commit to my remote master branch two commits are added: The merge commit from gallery-section-detached-head and the push commit to the remote master branch.

How do I make it so that there's only 1 commit when pushing merged detached head branches like when I push a merged "normal" branch? Would appreciate some help a lot on why it's happening and how to fix it.
EDIT2:
Exactly the same thing happens when I work on a branch that has been created in the past. Everything was done in the VS Code terminal. Here's an overview of my git commands:




here you see the two commits in the local branch:

and here on the remote branch:

I understand that it's happening because the readme branch was made in the past and afterwards a new branch has been created from and merged to the master branch. What I don't understand and find completely unnecessary and useless is why it's prompting me to add a push commit message and creating two commits when merging instead of simply using the commit message from the commit of the branch that's being merged to the master branch and creating one commit only.

Please edit your post and show us the output of the command git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all.

there you go @AntonioPetricca

You get an editor open when you run git push? Are you completely sure about that?

What tool do you use to do your push? Are you running git push from the command line, or are you running some other GUI or software on top of Git? git push should never give you such a prompt, so my guess is that this is coming from a layer on top of it.

added screenshots of every step I did including the end result
